# File upload is limited to 1M, even after PHP, Nginx, and Apache configuration

Tags: firewall, ubuntu-18.04, waf, web-application-firewall, juniper

I'm asking about an issue on a Wordpress website, that serves on an Ubuntu 18.04 behind of a WAF(Web Application Firewall) service.

The server was working for 1 year. 4 days ago I tried to upload a file and I got `Http` error.

`upload_max_filesize` and other values on configurations are about 2G.

First of all, I checked VM configs and I found out VM memory reduced to 4G. After increasing the memory amount, I did a check on **Vestacp** for the **PHP**, **Nginx**, and **Apache** configs, and they had no changes. Then I tried to upload, but this time on the local network and file uploaded successfully!

<del>here are the questions:</del>

- <del>Did I miss anything, while I checked the configurations?</del>
- <del>Is the WAF the reason of the problem?</del>
- <del>Is it a possibility that reducing and increasing the VM Memory amount, causing the problem?</del>

<del>And at last, how can I fix this?</del>

---

### Edited

Can someone explain the Juniper strategy and why it has done this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the WAF?

Comment: Did you verify the php settings via `phpinfo()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Double check your php.ini settings, look for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Both of those values affect the max upload size of a form. Also, dont forget to restart your server service after changes are made.

If that does not work, check the `phpinfo();` function output to make sure your settings saved and that the appropriate php.ini file is loaded. If so,

check code for `ini_set( ... )` functions. If there is one and it is changing it dynamically as the script executes, change it. Or, as a blanket fix, you can use that function and set the post max sizes to what you want. However, you should still investigate what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solved after bypassing the WAF

#### Edited `Feb 15, 2019`

According to the network security administrator investigation on the issue, after a couple of malicious requests to the Server, WAF made the right decision by blocking the rest of them. However, we are trying to find the source of the requests. As a theory, MSN Bot doing this.